# Error in printing Confusion Matrix for KNN algorithm

Tags: r, r-caret, knn, confusion-matrix

I want to try KNN algorithm on a dataset using R.I was able to perform KNN , but I want to check the **accuracy** of the model.
I tried to do the same with the help of `confusionMatrix` function,but it shows the following error.

```
Error in confusionMatrix.default(k, knn_test$driver_tset): 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference
```

The code is given below.

```
knn_data <- read.csv("Path/Data_without_Missing_values.csv")
knn_test<-read.csv("Path/Test.csv")
cl <- factor(knn_data[,4])
library('class') # required for knn()
k <- knn(knn_data[,c(1,2,3)], knn_test[,c(1,2,3)], cl)
library('caret') # required for confusionMatrix()
confusionMatrix(k,knn_test$driver_tset)
```

`driver_tset` is the column which I have to test. When I checked the levels of `k` and `knn_test$driver_tset`,it displays the following:

```
levels(k)
# [1] "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "17"

levels(knn_test$driver_tset)
# NULL`
```

So its clear that levels are different, but I'm not getting the significance of levels here. Also,how do I fix this?

Comment: are you using `caret`?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, but in general: the arguments to `caret::confusionMatrix()` are the predicted classes and the reference (actual) classes.  Your syntax is incorrect with respect to the first argument.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2: Yes I'm using the `caret` package.Even i have used the same argument here for `confusionMatrix`. `k` has the predicted values and `knn_test$driver_tset` has reference values

Comment: You are going to confuse everyone if you use `k` for predicted values instead of the algorithm constant for `knn()`.

Comment: Also, it appears that `knn_test$driver_tset` is **not a factor**, which is probably why your `confusionMatrix` isn't working.  But we can't help you because you haven't provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).